# Why are custom fields auto-populating in Salesforce upon completion of Docusign

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, auto-populate

I am trying to figure out why/how certain fields are auto-populating on my Opportunity object when I complete a Docusign.

The issue: On an Opportunity record I click a custom button that sends a DocuSign to a list of signers. When the last signer completes signing the document, and the DocuSign Status is marked as completed I refresh the Opportunity record and 2 custom fields have been populated with today's date.

Here are the items I have already looked into to trouble shoot the issue:

1. On the fields themselves, I have clicked the 'where is this used?'  button, and the only places these fields are used are in Page layouts and reports. It is NOT referenced in any apex classes or process builders.
2. I have looked through all my workflow rules, and field updates on those workflow rules. These fields are not referenced in any of the workflows/field updates.
3. I have set field history tracking on the fields and found that the change is being made by an integration user. I then set up a debug log on the integration user and in all of the debug logs there is no reference to the fields being updated there.
4. In a sandbox I tried deleting the field to see if it might be referenced by a Custom metadata type, and no errors were thrown saying it was. I have also looked into the custom settings and custom metadata types to see if the reference to these fields could be in there.

Hoping someone can let me know if they've seen this issue before, or know any other ways to troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there's been some custom configuration setup, out of the box the package shouldn't add new fields to the opportunity record that are updated upon completion of an envelope. All of that information should only be found on the DocuSign Status object initially.

I would recommend reaching out to the DocuSign support team and have them take a look at the configuration with you to see what may be happening. https://support.docusign.com/